# Material Design lite menu

Tags: html, css, material-design

I am using material design lite.

In my dashboard menu i am trying to display 4 tabs.

I have tried in many ways to display 4 tabs on my dashboard URL.

This is my dashboard menu ---

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbKVko

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Uses a header that scrolls with the text, rather than staying
      locked at the top -->
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--scroll">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <!-- Title -->
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Chris</span>
          <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <!-- Navigation -->
          <nav class="mdl-navigation">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard 2</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard 3</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard 4</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Chris</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard 2</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard 3</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard 4</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my tab menu which i am trying to add on my dashboard menu ---
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKkvgA

Any one knows how i can merge this 2 and display 4 tabs only on the dashboard menu selection !

Any advice or suggestion will be really appreciate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Uses a header that scrolls with the text, rather than staying
      locked at the top -->
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--scroll">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <!-- Title -->
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Chris</span>
          <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <!-- Navigation -->
          <nav class="mdl-navigation">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard 2</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard 3</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard 4</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- Tabs -->
        <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
            <a href="#dashboard_tab_1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Dashboard Tab 1</a>
            <a href="#dashboard_tab_2" class="mdl-layout__tab">Dashboard Tab 2</a>
            <a href="#dashboard_tab_3" class="mdl-layout__tab">Dashboard Tab 3</a>
            <a href="#dashboard_tab_4" class="mdl-layout__tab">Dashboard Tab 4</a>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Chris</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard 2</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard 3</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard 4</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your great answer, but what i want is when i select Only dashboard2 than the 4 tabs appears, not for dashboard, dashboard3 and dashboard 4 !! Do you know how i can do it !!! Thanks a lot again for your great answer :)

Comment: Make a HTML file for each dashboard page (dashboard1.html, dashboard2.html, dashboard3.html and dashboard4.html) and only add the tab HTML code to the dashboard2.html page. Just make sure that the different HTML pages are linking to each other !